# How to flatten the result set

Tags: sql, t-sql, common-table-expression, window-functions, row-number

Got a big of a mind stopping question.  Need to flatted the sql result set from multiple records per EMPLOYEECODE to one.  Keeping the min STARTIME and showing the max ENDTIME for each record.
Hope the images are explanatory. Would love to have an idea how to deliver it. THANKS!

[The raw result set](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6UGMi.png)

[Required result set](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Nrjr.png)

Comment: Please read [this](https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for some tips on improving your question. Reasons not to use images are [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/92546).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming there are no shifts that go past midnight for a given date you could use this:

SELECT EMPLOYEECODE, SHIFTDATE, MIN(STARTTIME),MAX(STOPTIME),MIN(START_TIME),MAX(STOP_TIME)
FROM TABLENAME
GROUP BY EMPLOYEECODE;

Comment: Oh...so simple! Thank you, Nikkorian!!! I've been struggling to max, mins over partitions.  3 cte's along the way....Thanks!  Massive help, Nikkorian!